# Flex item with justify-content: space-between is not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a menu bar with sub-menus. I want on the same line as the menu an "Account" or "Profile" link on the right, and I want to do it with pure CSS3/Flex.

But I guess there is something wrong in my css code because the last link ("Account") is diplaying under the main menu, so my `justify-content: space-between` for the nav element is not working. How can I do it ?

Here my code :

```css
nav {
    font-size: 20px ;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 ;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px #DDDDDD;
    background-color: white;
}

nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

nav a {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another longer submenu here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Yet another submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Etc. etc.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">Account</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you simply remove `position: absolute` from `nav ul`, then `space-between` will work. It doesn't work in your code because [***absolutely-positioned flex items do not participate in flex layout***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just found my error.

```
nav ul { position: absolute; }
```

should not be positionned here, but here :

```
nav ul li ul { position: absolute; }
```

So the snippet fixed (hope it could help someone else)...

```css
nav {
    font-size: 20px ;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 ;
    background-color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px #DDDDDD;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;        
}
nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

nav a {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another longer submenu here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Yet another submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Etc. etc.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My submenu 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">Account</a>
</nav>
```